# Filter data on the basis of selected days of the week using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

**I need to write a query to filter data on the basis of selected date range and days**

Query:-

```
 Expression<Func<Task, bool>> filterPredicate =
                s => s.Active && !s.Deleted && s.StartDateTime != null && s.EndDateTime != null &&
                s.StartDateTime >= startDate && s.StartDateTime <= endDate;
```

The selected Date range filter is working fine but I need help to filter data if a user has selected days of the week e.g Monday, Tuesday along with the date range

Comment: Assuming a T-SQL back-end, use the [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart?view=netframework-4.8) method to have Entity Framework inject a call to the [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) SQL function. Use `'weekday'` (aka `'dw'`) to get the day of the week.

Comment: The days parameter is an array of integer. e.g user has selected 0,1. Then I want to fetch the tasks from database which lies between the selected date range and the task is active on Sunday or Monday

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 0):

It's something like this... You should know if this addictional condition is and/or and know if startDate and endDate has the same value.
Supposing that StartDateTime is a DateTime type.

```
Expression<Func<Task, bool>> filterPredicate =
            s => s.Active && !s.Deleted && s.StartDateTime != null && s.EndDateTime != null &&
            s.StartDateTime >= startDate && s.StartDateTime <= endDate || s.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek == selectedDayOfWeek  && s.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek == selectedDayOfWeek;
```

Comment: The days parameter is an array of integer. e.g user has selected 0,1. Then I want to fetch the tasks from database which lies between the selected date range and the task is active on Sunday or Monday.

Comment: In that case, use `selectedDaysOfWeek.Contains(s.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek)`.